# How to make exceptions for url securing app with Keycloak?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

We have an app on Wildfly Server, secured with keycloak, everything works fine, but now we have to make an access for an app, deployed on the same server. I don't want to write a "complex" code with all certificates for https and OAuth2, we use for it, but I would like to grant an access for the second app from localhost, to make request on the first one (via rest-api) and get an response. When I check with curl from terminal of the server - I get also an Unathorized-Error, so I need to do all the same operations as for public access (take Token for access from OAuth provider). How could I set up Keycloak, to grant an access from localhost, for example. I haven't found smth. equal neither in Keycloak nor in standalone-full.xml (there are no any properties for this), where I could put exclusions.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -2):

Add localhost to `Valid Redirect Uris` and `Web Origins` of Keycloak's client or you can simply use `*` for development purposes so that all Uris are valid.

Comment: That doesn't cover his need. He wants to bypass KC when calling from localhost, AFAIK this is not possible out of the box.